# Dealing with obstructed SATA ports on motherboard

Tags: motherboard, sata, cable

I have an older motherboard that I can't afford to replace just yet; it's the Biostar TForce 6100 AM2.

[image]

I recently purchased an expensive video card which is dual-width and quite large. This video card extends over the sata ports and does not have any room for straight sata cables to connect.

I managed to connect one hard drive with a sata cable with a right-angle connector, but since both ports are oriented the same direction, I can only hook up one drive this way. Is there some place to buy a "left" right-angle connector cable so I can hook up the other drive? Or do you have any other suggestions for me?

Ultimately I do plan to buy another motherboard in the Spring; I'm just hoping for an inexpensive solution to tide me over until then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check [satacables.com](http://www.satacables.com/) and scroll down to:

SATA II Device (signal) Cable **Left Angle** to Straight Connectors

[image]

Comment: That particular one looks like the right-angle-to-straight that I have. But the one below it, left-angle-to-right-angle, looks like it'll work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16812119229

Comment: sorry, this looks like a "right angle to straight" to me.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.auspcmarket.com.au/
search for CB-S7P7P-2X90-100

it's a 90 to 90, one looks left, one looks right.